# Cómo se le dice al acto o acción de proveer?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

Por ejemplo, el acto o acción de administrar es "administración". Cómo se llamaría, si existe, al acto o acción de proveer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In most of its senses although not all the word seems to be *provisión*.

From the DLE http://dle.rae.es/?id=UUTE3Ja

> 1. f. Acción y efecto de proveer.
> 2. f. Prevención de mantenimientos, caudales u otras cosas que se ponen en alguna parte para cuando hagan falta.
> 3. f. Conjunto de cosas, especialmente alimentos, que se guardan o reservan para un fin. U. m. en pl.
> 4. f. Providencia o disposición conducente al logro de algo.
> 5. f. Despacho o mandamiento que en nombre del rey expedían algunos tribunales para que se ejecutase lo que por ellos se ordenaba.